# Is a subset $B= {(-\infty,t),t\in \mathbb{R} }$ an event of sample space $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

The sample space $\omega$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Here is a subset $B= {(-\infty,t),t\in \mathbb{R} }$. So $B \in \beta(\mathbb{R})$. Is this subset an event? How to show that ? If it is an event, is it because it is Borel?

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathscr{B}$ is the Borel sigma-field of $\mathbb{R}$, we know, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that the intervals $(t-n,t)$ belong to $\mathscr{B}$. Therefore, $B=(-\infty,t)$ is in $\mathscr{B}$, because it may be written as a denumerable union of the former intervals: $B=\cup_{n=1}^\infty (t-n,t)$, and, as a sigma-field, $\mathscr{B}$ must be closed under denumerable unions of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

An *event* is a measurable subset of a probability space. In order to say whether a given subset is measurable, one must have identified the sigma-algebra of measurable subsets with which one is working.

It is common in mathematical analysis to turn the real numbers into a measurable space by associating $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel sigma-algebra -- the sigma-algebra generated by the open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. In this standard case, the subset $(-\infty,t)$ is Borel-measurable for all $t$, per the argument of @Zen.

However, while the Borel sigma-algebra is canonical, it is not obligatory. As a counter-example, one could turn $\mathbb{R}$ into a measurable space by equipping this set with the sigma-algebra consisting only of $\mathbb{R}$ and the empty set. In this alternative case, $(-\infty,t)$ is not a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This sentence **"In order to say whether a given subset is measurable, one must define the measure being used"** is mathematically incorrect.

Comment: We don't have to specify any measure to say which subsets are events. All we need is some set $\mathscr{X}$ and a sigma-field $\mathscr{A}$ of subsets of $\mathscr{X}$. These are considerations about the **measurable space** $(\mathscr{X},\mathscr{A})$. We don't need to consider a **measure space** $(\mathscr{X},\mathscr{A},\mu)$, for any measure $\mu$ (finite or not), to answer this question.

Comment: And, please, I'm pointing this because a lot of students get information from SE. I don't mean to be rude. Not at all.

Comment: @Zen is correct, and I was mistaken. I have edited my answer accordingly.